# Texmaker pdf viewer works only while embedded but depending on extension monitor

Tags: texmaker, viewers, screen

I have the problem described in the title ([exactly as in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333268/texmaker-internal-pdf-viewer-only-works-when-embedded)).

**Problem:**

While having the pdf viewer embedded there is no problem.
When unchecking the embedded option, I cannot open the separate pdf viewer window, neither from the taskbar, nor with ALT+TAB. Both, while hovering the cursor over the taskbar symbol and with ALT+TAB the pdf viewer window appears empty but still cannot be accessed.

**In addition to the other question on this problem**, I have noticed: The problem occurs dependent on the connection to certain extension monitors (connected to my laptop to extend the screen).
I am working with 3 different extension monitors (dependent on where I work for the day) and always the same laptop.
Let's call the monitors: *A* (a flat screen TV), *B1*, and *B2* (regular pc monitors).
The monitors have different dimensions and resolutions.
If the problem occurs on *A*, the *B* monitors don't have the problem and vice versa. I have experienced the problem on monitor *A* a couple of months ago and now on the *B* monitors (and now also while working on the laptop without screen extension, but not while extending with *A*). I have not changed any settings and am puzzled why this problem occurred in the first place and how it changed from the *A* monitor to the *B* monitors.

The problem persists independent of the content of the tex-file (so no minimum working code or try the code in the linked question). Compilation exited without errors and a pdf file to view exists.
The problem occurred in Texmaker 5.0.2 and also after updating to 5.0.3. running on Windows 10 pro.

**Questions:**

How can I get rid of the problem?
How does screen extension or the characteristics of the extension monitor matter for Texmaker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I’ve figured it out ...

While experiencing the problem with an extension monitor attached, changing the primary screen between the monitors (desktop display settings) makes the integrated pdf viewer window accessible.

Afterwards the viewer window stays accessible, also without using an extension monitor.

Answer (score 0):

When Texmaker 5 is  started with the PDF preview  window embedded it generally stores the necessary PDF view settings in Texmaker.ini however when the PDF viewer is dis-embedded the settings are stored in a separate file texmakerpdfview.ini.

For different monitor profiles this may need to be changed on a per installation basis, thus once you have a setting for monitor A, at the end of session you could store that as texmakerpdfview.a and for monitor B store as texmakerpdfview.b Then in a startup script simply over write texmakerpdfview.ini with texmakerpdfview.a or texmakerpdfview.b accordingly.

Much simpler just have a shortcut to delete texmakerpdfview.ini and let it rebuild on first view of a PDF

Comment: Thanks for the insight! This helps to understand why the problem occurred and is much appreciated. Since the other answer I found a day before your post works and seems to be simpler than writing a startup script / defining a shortcut, I accepted that other answer.